# Can you put a full attribute (both name and value) in an element from a string in Razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I know you can do this in asp.net MVC Razor Engine:

```html
@{
  string myValue = "foo"
}

<h1 hello='@myValue'></h1>
```

But i rather wanna do this, but it will cause an error:

```html
@{
  string myAttribute = "hello='foo'";
}

<h1 @myAttribute></h1>
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve?

Comment: `@{ string myAttribute = "hello=foo"; } <h1 @myAttribute></h1>` (no quotes around `foo`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

```html
@{
  string myAttribute = "hello=foo";
}

<h1 @myAttribute></h1>
```

Without the quotes.
Thank you Stephen Muecke